# Is it possible to find a sender's Public PGP (GPG) key from an encoded message?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Could you find the sender's Public PGP (GPG) key from an encoded message?

Comment: Did you mean "Encoded" or "Encrypted"?

Answer (score 7):

Encrypted messages only contain the *recipients'* key IDs (and even that can be disabled).

You can only find the sender's key ID if the message was also *signed* – but the signature is encrypted too, so you're out of luck.

Either way, you would only find the key *ID*, not the key itself.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, what @grawity said.

Additionally, some email clients do send the senders public key as another attachment automatically.

And/or you can search for the sender's public key on a keyserver using command line:

```
gpg --search-keys senders@email.com
```

or alternatively on the keyserver's web interface, like http://pgp.mit.edu/
Sender must have uploaded the key to the keyserver, of course.